# WITH statement, invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle, errors

Using the below as an example:

```
WITH
    V_TBL1 (ID,NAME) AS (SELECT ID,NAME FROM TABLE1),
    V_TBL2 (TIME) AS (SELECT TIME FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.ID IN (V_TBL1.ID))
    
    SELECT * FROM V_TBL2
;
```

Why does Oracle throw the error?

```
-- *V_TBL1.ID: Invalid Identifier* line 3
```

I'm sure I've used this before and it's worked, I can't see what I'm doing wrong this time.

Answer (score 2):

The [`IN` predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html#GUID-C7961CB3-8F60-47E0-96EB-BDCF5DB1317C) accepts either an explicit list of values or a subquery (returning a single column in this case).

In your query, the right side of `IN` is a list consisting of a single value, where the value is a reference.  The reference is invalid because `V_TBL1` is undefined in that context.  If you want to check that `TABLE2.ID` is included in the `V_TBL1` set, you have to use the subquery syntax:

```
SELECT TIME FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.ID IN (SELECT V_TBL1.ID FROM V_TBL1)
```

> I'm sure I've used this before and it's worked

I believe your memory is failing you there, that syntax cannot possibly have worked.